# How to resolve @Stateless annotation on EJB?

Tags: java, rest, ejb

I'm trying to create an EJB but the @Stateless annotation says it cannot be resolved. I downloaded a couple of .jars and added the dependecy below to make it work but still no luck. What am I missing ?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>7.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .m2 folder is this jar downloaded and you have jar in build path. @Stateless should be in same jar as you  mentioned. Package will be javax.ejb.Stateless if you open the jar you can find it.

My guess is its classpath issue. Clean and build your project by removing jars from .m2

```
<dependency>

        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```